Opengl ES color blending is not accurate
I am developing a drawing app and I encountered a problem.
As you can see the color blending feature in opengl es is not accurate.
On the left side of the picture is blended through standard equation.
On the right side of the picture is blended through opengl.
Here are some fragments of my code.
//where I clear the buffer
GLES3_ClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
GLES3_Clear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

//where I set blending function
GLES3_Enable(GL_BLEND);
GLES3_BlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
GLES3_BlendEquationSeparate(GL_FUNC_ADD, GL_FUNC_ADD);

//here is the code I calculate expected value
//note that red2 and alpha2 represent the texture on the top
val expectRed = red2 * alpha2 + red1 * alpha1 * (1.0f - alpha2)
val expectGreen = green2 * alpha2 + green1 * alpha1 * (1.0f - alpha2)
val expectBlue = blue2 * alpha2 + blue1 * alpha1 * (1.0f - alpha2)
val expectAlpha = 1.0f - (1.0f - alpha2) * (1.0f - alpha1)
val expectColor = Color.argb(
            (expectAlpha * 0xFF).toInt(),
            (expectRed * 0xFF).toInt(),
            (expectGreen * 0xFF).toInt(),
            (expectBlue * 0xFF).toInt(),
        )

//here is the code for the people interested in how I create framebuffer
GLES3_GenTextures(1, &mTexture);
GLES3_GenFramebuffers(1, &mFramebuffer);
GLES3_BindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTexture);
GLES3_TexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, mWidth, mHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        nullptr);
GLES3_TexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
GLES3_TexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
GLES3_TexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES3_TexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES3_BindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, mFramebuffer);
GLES3_FramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTexture, 0);

GLES3_GenRenderbuffers(1, &mRenderBuffer);
GLES3_BindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, mRenderBuffer);
GLES3_RenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, mWidth, mHeight);
GLES3_FramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER,
        mRenderBuffer);



This could be the difference between blending in linear space vs gamma space. How have you set up your framebuffer — is it sRGB or linear?

Can you provided the code for how you got the sample on the left? Hard to match the control, without knowing how the control is generated / captured.

@DMGregory Can you care to explain the differences? I reupload the code. I hope this will helpful. And I also find interesting that there is no definition of GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB. So I guess sRGB is not working on Android

@Pikalek yes, I reupload the code. I am sure it's bug free. I have tested multiple time and pretty sure it's linear.
